# Vertically center NSTextAttachment in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nstextattachment

I have an custom `NSTextAttachment` class which I use to scale images inside a `UITextView` (based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150241)). This works great in `portrait` mode. In `landscape` mode, the images do not cover the whole screen and I want to center them in the `textview`.

Making changes to the bounds in the custom class (in `attachmentBoundsForTextContainer:`) does not make a difference (tried changing both `x` and `y` in the bounds). How else can this be changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vertically center the content of a UITextView.**

In viewWillAppear of your UIViewController.

```
textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .New, context: nil)
```

In viewWillDisappear of your UIViewController.

```
textView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
```

Override observeValueForKeyPath in your UIViewController.

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if keyPath == "contentSize" {

        let height = textView.bounds.size.height
        let contentHeight = textView.contentSize.height
        let zoom = textView.zoomScale
        let top = (height - contentHeight * zoom) / 2.0
        textView.contentInset.top = top < 0.0 ? 0.0 : top
    }
}
```

**Horizontally center the content of an NSAttributtedString inside a UITextView.**

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
let attachmentAttrString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
let result = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attachmentAttrString)

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center

let attrs:[String:AnyObject] = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
let range = NSMakeRange(0, result.length)
result.addAttributes(attrs, range: range)

textView.attributedText = result
```